# Add new class to new data from Ajax with JSON data type

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, oracle-jet

My `Ajax` request is working fine and returning the desired data. But i want to add new `class` to `<li>` element which i am getting from `AJAX` request. I am trying to add new class i.e `$elm.addClass("newclass")` under Ajax `success`, but i am not seeing this new class being added to new `li` elements. There is no error. i am not sure whats wrong with this as i am not getting any error also.

```
function  loadSuccess(data, status, obj)
 {


for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var nodeid = data[i].attr.id;

    if (nodeid=="BALX") {

        $("#"+nodeid).addClass("selected");

    }
 }


};
```

**HTML--From Chrome Inspector-->first time--Parent Node--**

```
  <ul role="tree"   style="outline:none">
        <li role="treeitem" id="ALLACCOUNTS" <span >ALLACCOUNTS --1</span></a></li>
 </ul>
```

**---------------after clicking on the parent node "ALLACCOUNTS"--Its a Ajax call-----**

```
   <ul role="tree"  style="outline:none"><li role="treeitem" id="ALLACCOUNTS" ><a  class=""><span class="oj-tree-title">ALLACCOUNTS --1</span></a><ul class="" style="overflow: hidden; display: block;"><li id="BALX" ><a ><span >BALSHEET --2</span></a></li></ul></li></ul>
```

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle? If you set a breakpoint on `$("#"+nodeid).addClass("selected");` does the console show a matched result for $('#BALX')?

Comment: @mwilson:- Yes, it is going into the IF clause and i can see the nodeid with BALX in the DOM. it is that it is not adding new class to this element. I am not sure if Ajax Success is the right place for this kind of manipulation.

Comment: Is your nodeid is proper id? print it on browser console

Comment: I posted an answer below using a bogus jsfiddle ajax call. Try and make sure yours matches up with fine (except the url). I am still willing to be it's your selector, however. Show us your HTML for the BALX element

Comment: If you are looking for the added class from console. Try closing the console and inspect it again. Or add some red border for the selected class try. Addclass must be working but sometimes it might not be visible in console.

Comment: Is that ID value unique in your DOM?

Comment: can you post your ajax code and its url file ,Because I want to check return data

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of what you're trying to accomplish. I think you might be off on your selected. Try making sure jquery is actually finding the element using developer tools:

https://jsfiddle.net/9j429sw4/

**HTML**

```
<div id="test1">Test 1</div>
<div id="test2">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3">Test 3</div>
<div id="test4">Test 4</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.selected {
  background-color: green;
  color: red;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
var ids = ["test1", "test2", "test3", "test4"];
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '/echo/json',
    success: function (response) {
      for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
          if (ids[i] == "test2") $("#"+ids[i]).addClass('selected');
      }
    },
    error: function (err) {
      alert('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: :- thanks for quickly creating it. In my case, initially i am loading with single node say "Parent" and then we click on Parent Node then i am loading its children node and when click on children node then i am loading its children. During these ajax call , i am trying to apply the new classes to these children nodes. I can see these children node loading but without the selection and also when i inspect the DOM there i dont find this new class added to these children nodes.

Comment: If you open the developer tools and set a break point where you're expecting to apply that class and try and find that dom element using your console, it will answer all your questions. I promise

Comment: the new UL element for children node will be added only when i click on its parent , so for breakpoint new node is not there. I think in Ajax SUCCESS, new node is not available to apply the new class as Node is newly created through same Ajax request

Answer (score 0):

Try using .class instead of #id.
And look for this element with your `console.log( $("#"+nodeid) );` to verify if this really exists.
Maybe you have more than onde #id element and get some error.

Force this with `$("#nodeid_name").addClass('selected');` right into your browser console, like `$("#BALX").addClass('selected');` and see what happens.